# ASN1 file parsing using JAVA

Tags: java, parsing, asn.1

One of my projects requires to me to parse an ASN.1 file, and put its data into database. Is there any JAVA api or any other way which can parse the ASN.1 file using JAVA.

Comment: Tried this?-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190795/parsing-asn-1-binary-data-with-java

Answer (score 0):

There is a great list of ASN.1 Tools at http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx which includes a section for Java Tools.  There are both commercial and free tools listed here.  Using a good tool will save you a lot of time and frustration when working with the details of encoding and decoding ASN.1 messages.