# How to convert OpenSSL digital signature to ASN1?

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, asn.1

Using the openssl library I have created a digital signature of a file.

I can see that if I use the openssl command:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin -asn1parse -in sigfile
```

I get a nice output of something like:

```
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      
  0000 - c9 8c 24 b6 77 ef f4 48-60 af ea 6f 49 3b ba ec   ..$.w..H`..oI;..
  0010 - 5b b1 c4 cb b2 09 c6 fc-2b bb 47 f6 6f f2 ad 31   [.......+.G.o..1
```

How can I programmatically convert my signature file into some ASN1 that I can then parse?

Comment: The output you see is *not* ASN.1, it is a string representation of encoded ASN.1 designed for perusal and debugging. So what are you really asking?

Comment: I'm aware the output isn't asn.1, I'm also aware that the signature isn't either. My question is how did openssl go from the signature to some asn.1 that they could then parse and display that pretty string representation...

Comment: The output of openssl is an ASN.1 sequence containing the recovered data of the RSA signature: the digest algorithm  and the decrypted digest (the original digest of your content)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/rsautl.html) `-verify` command outputs the recovered data of the RSA signature

> -verify
> verify the input data and output the recovered data.

It means that is returning the PKCS#1 message. A digital signature following the [RFC2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313)  is composed of the digest algorithm identifier and the encrypted digest of the content with the RSA private key in PKCS#7 format, described in section 9.1 of [RFC2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315#section-9.1).

```
signedData ::= SEQUENCE {
 version Version,
 digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
 contentInfo ContentInfo,
 certificates
    [0] IMPLICIT ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates
      OPTIONAL,
 crls
   [1] IMPLICIT CertificateRevocationLists OPTIONAL,
 signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

So (if I understood correctly...), **the output of openssl is an ASN.1 sequence of digest algoritm + decrypted digest (the original digest of your content)**

To decode it you can use [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org)

```
public class ASN1Decoder {
    private static String opensslOutputB64= "MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIGGbJmsmf9lg/jeaXjm0XsUZ4ZS7xv0Da/NvPoNiRzRO";
    
    public final static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException{
        ASN1InputStream bIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(opensslOutputB64)));
         ASN1Primitive obj = bIn.readObject();
         System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(obj));
        
    }
}
```

Check [Parsing ASN.1 binary data with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190795/parsing-asn-1-binary-data-with-java) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

With some help from @pedrofb I managed to come up with the following solution:

```
// Get key from cert
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("/home/administrator/Downloads/cert_1.txt"));
PublicKey key = cer.getPublicKey();

// or read key in from pem file
PublicKey publicKey = ManifestUtils.publicKeyFromPemFile(new FileReader("/home/administrator/Downloads/publickey.txt"));

// Decrypt the signature
Cipher asymmetricCipher
            = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
asymmetricCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] plainText = asymmetricCipher.doFinal(
            IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("/home/administrator/Downloads/signature.sign")));

// print as hex
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(plainText));

// Print the ans1 nicely - ish
ASN1InputStream input = new ASN1InputStream(plainText);
ASN1Primitive p;
while ((p = input.readObject()) != null) {
    System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(p));
}
```