# JASN1 decoding ASN java.io.IOException: Length is out of bound

Tags: java, binaryfiles, asn.1

I have compiled an asn1 file format and I have got my .class Java files using Jasn.
Now I want to decode the input stream from my asn format file.
The decode method have two inputs: ( inputStream, Beridentifier)

```
 BerIdentifier b = new BerIdentifier(BerIdentifier.CONTEXT_CLASS, BerIdentifier.CONSTRUCTED, 1);
```

Now i am getting io.exception : Length is out of bound!

Comment: Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190795/parsing-asn-1-binary-data-with-java

Comment: Thanks , i have already tried bountycastle api but it may result wrong datas .

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to include what you have tried, the data that is wrong, then the exception that occurs.

Comment: I have setted the Beridentifier Object but i get now this exception :java.io.IOException: Length is out of bound!