# Converting output of ASN1Dump.dumpAsString to a class in java

Tags: java, asn.1

I'm new to ASN1 notation and I'm struck where I'm not able to proceed further. I'm able to dump the output using ASN1Dump.dumpAsString() [Referred from [link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190795/parsing-asn-1-binary-data-with-java)

I'm able to get a dump(see example below). But I want to extract individual values and use them. How can I convert it to a class or access individual oids?

```
Sequence
    DER Set
        Sequence
            ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.4.1.4843.1.1)
            PrintableString(testValue1) 
    DER Set
        Sequence
            ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.4.1.4843.1.2)
            PrintableString(testValue2) 
    DER Set
        Sequence
            ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.4.1.4843.1.3)
            PrintableString(testValue3)
```

I want something like this..

```
t.getValue("1.3.6.1.4.1.4843.1.1") should return testValue1 where t is of type some TestClass which contains members of testValue1,testValue2,testValue3.
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that, if you could use `ASN1Dump`, then you already have the object with the structure above.

For this answer, I've created the same structure (as I don't have your original data), but with minor differences (`DERSequence` instead of just `Sequence`), but the logic is basically the same.

You'll need to parse the asn1 structure and store the fields you want. For this code, I used **bouncycastle 1.46 jdk1.6**.

First, you create `TestClass` with a constructor that parses the object (the same object you passed to `ASN1Dump.dumpAsString()`. I'm assuming it's a `DERSequence` - probably is, but it can also be a `ASN1Sequence` (do a `obj.getClass()` to make sure). The code wouldn't change because `ASN1Sequence` is a super class of `DERSequence` and the methods used belongs to the super class.

```
public class TestClass {
    // this map will contain the values (key is 1.3.6.etc and value is testValue1, testValue2...)
    private Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public TestClass(DERSequence sequence) {
        // parse objects from sequence
        Enumeration<?> objects = sequence.getObjects();
        while (objects.hasMoreElements()) {
            DERSet set = (DERSet) objects.nextElement(); // casting because I know from dump it's a DERSet

            // I'm assuming it's a DERSequence, but do a System.out.println(set.getObjectAt(0).getClass()) to make sure and cast accordinly
            DERSequence seq = (DERSequence) set.getObjectAt(0);

            // I'm assuming it's a DERObjectIdentifier, but do a System.out.println(set.getObjectAt(0).getClass()) to make sure and cast accordinly
            DERObjectIdentifier oid = (DERObjectIdentifier) seq.getObjectAt(0); // this object contains 1.3.6.etc...

            // I'm assuming it's a DERPrintableString, but do a System.out.println(set.getObjectAt(1).getClass()) to make sure and cast accordinly
            DERPrintableString str = (DERPrintableString) seq.getObjectAt(1);

            // store the values in the map
            fields.put(oid.getId(), str.getString());
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String oid) {
        // optional: you can check for null, or if oid exists (fields.contains(oid)), and return "" or null when it doesn't
        return fields.get(oid);
    }
}
```

After that, you can use `TestClass` this way:

```
// assuming seq is the object you passed to ASN1Dump.dumpAsString
// check if its type is DERSequence (do a seq.getClass() to check)
// if it's another type of sequence, change the TestClass code accordingly, as already explained above
TestClass t = new TestClass(seq);
System.out.println(t.getValue("1.3.6.1.4.1.4843.1.1")); // prints testValue1
```

PS: note that I've just parsed following the structure printed by `ASN1Dump`:

- the object is a sequence that contains 3 sets

  - each set contains just one element, which is a sequence

    - each sequence contains 2 elements: an object identifier and a printable string

I've just went through the elements until I've got the ones I want.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. I also wanted whether writing custom parsing logic is the only way to parse custom subject name values in x.509 certificate? Above dump is a custom subject name in x.509 certificate.

`ASN1InputStream asnInputStream = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(clientCertificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded()));
ASN1Primitive obj = asnInputStream.readObject();
System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(obj));`

Comment: For Subject Name, I prefer to call `getSubjectX500Principal().toString()` and parse the string using `StringTokenizer`